# Data structures for building an incremental tree in Java

Tags: java

I want to build an incremental tree in Java and show this tree in Frontend after converting it to JSON. If the user checks or unchecks a particular node then all the nodes below this particular node will get affected. Which data structure should I use ? Is there any ay tree implementaton in Java readily available in apache commons or guava ?

Answer (score 0):

In pure Java there is implementation from Swing look at [TreeNode class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) For serialization to JSON you can use for example [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). I am not aware of any all-in-one solution.

Comment: btw, "checks or unchecks" from you question implies you are developing some GUI application, could you provide more information about the used framework?